# i want to filter the last command output to last "x" hours, it can be 1 hr or 2yr etc. i used everything grep/sed/awk but nothing is helping me out

Tags: linux, bash

tried this grep but it will give only specific hours details.

```
 last -n  -x reboot shutdown |  sed -n "/$(date --date='0 hours ago' '+%a %b %d %H')/,\${/$(date --date='12 hours ago' '+%a %b %d %H')/q;p}"

reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1062.el7. Tue Jun 23 06:21 - 09:18  (02:56)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1062.el7. Tue Jun 23 06:14 - 09:18  (03:03)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1062.el7. Tue Jun 23 06:05 - 09:18  (03:12)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1062.el7. Tue Jun 23 05:52 - 09:18  (03:25)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1062.el7. Tue Jun 23 05:19 - 09:18  (03:58)
shutdown system down  3.10.0-1062.el7. Tue Jun 23 05:19 - 05:19  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1062.el7. Mon Jun 22 12:29 - 05:19  (16:49)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1062.el7. Mon Jun 22 07:12 - 05:19  (22:07)
shutdown system down  3.10.0-1062.el7. Mon Jun 22 07:12 - 07:12  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1062.el7. Mon Jun 22 03:57 - 07:12  (03:14)
shutdown system down  3.10.0-1062.el7. Mon Jun 22 02:38 - 03:57  (01:18)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1062.el7. Mon Jun 22 02:20 - 02:38  (00:18)
shutdown system down  3.10.0-1062.el7. Mon Jun 22 02:20 - 02:20  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1062.el7. Mon Jun 22 01:48 - 02:20  (00:32)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1062.el7. Fri May  1 09:25 - 02:20 (51+16:55)
shutdown system down  3.10.0-1062.el7. Fri May  1 09:25 - 09:25  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-1062.el7. Fri May  1 09:24 - 09:25  (00:00)
shutdown system down  3.10.0-1062.el7. Wed Jan 15 09:25 - 09:24 (106+22:59)
```

Comment: Can you define/elaborate  `i used everything grep/sed/awk`: show us, even failed attempts

Comment: last -n2  -x reboot shutdown | grep "$(date -d '-2 hour' +'%H')"..........last -n2  -x reboot shutdown | awk -vDate=`date -d'now-2 hours' +%a %b %d %H:%M` '$4 > Date {print Date, $0}'.............. last -n  -x reboot shutdown |  sed -n "/$(date --date='0 hours ago' '+%a %b %d %H')/,\${/$(date --date='12 hours ago' '+%a %b %d %H')/q;p}"

Comment: Always add them to your [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62536886/edit)

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the period to `last`

```
last --since -2hours
```

Comment: In CentOS/RHEL 7.x, the command `last` doesn't have this options.

Comment: Sure. But! The question is tagged with [linux].

Comment: Yes correct In CentOS/RHEL 7.x,  does not have "since option". that is the reason i was using the grep. in grep what happens is if we grep, it will not satisfy the range of hours. =>last -n2  -x reboot shutdown | grep "$(date -d '-2 hour' +'%H')"...... this will just return the details of second hour from now, suppose now the time is 6pm, it will fetch only details of 4pm, it will not include 5pm details. we can give range like [4-6] but how to calculate that when my only input to program is "last 'x' hours", depending on x we need to calculate range.